# Rot13 obfuscation in Assembly language doesn't work correctly

Tags: assembly, encryption, rot13

I'm trying to do the rot13 in assembly wherein you have to input 10 lowercase letters and outputs it after rot13 encryption. However, it's not working correctly. I don't know how else to fix it because I just started learning assembly recently. Please help me.

```
.model small
.data
   arr dd 10 dup(?), '$'
.stack 100h
.code
main proc

mov ax, @data
mov ds, ax

mov si, 0

    scan:                       ; gets input from user

        mov ah, 01h                 ; get input
        int 21h 
        mov bx, offset arr
        mov byte ptr [bx+si], al
        add si, 1                       ; increment si <-- array index

    cmp si, 9                   ; compare si to 9
    jle scan                    ; (loop) if si <= 9, jump to scan

mov si, 0

    print:                      ; display the input of user
        mov al, [si]

        cmp al, 'n'
        jb plus

        cmp al, 'n'
        jae minus

        plus:
            mov al, [si]
            add al, 13
            jmp alwaysRun

        minus:
            mov al, [si]
            sub al, 13

        alwaysRun:
            mov dl, al              
            mov ah, 02h                 ; print
            int 21h
            add si, 1                       

    cmp si, 9
    jle print

mov ax, 4c00h
int 21h 

main endp
end main
```

Comment: "It is not working correctly" is *never* a good error description, please amend. What have you tried? Are you running a debugger?

Comment: Learn to use a debugger yourself. Step through the code, see where it does something you didn't intend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main error is `mov al, [si]`. It is not guaranteed that `arr` starts at 0 - and actually it doesn't. Change it to `[bx+si]` (offset of `arr` plus index) like in the input block.